# Entity Framework is not working in class library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have created a class library project in VS2010 ultimate with .net 4.0 and Entity fwk-4.1.

After adding a ref to the Entity framework dll, I am not able to use the Data Annotation attributes like 'Required' on class properties.

Could you please let me know what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Required` attribute is defined inside `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace and is available in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly(dll)

1)  Make sure to add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly(dll)

2) Add a using statement to import the  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace in your class file.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class YourModel
{
  [Required]
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
```